# mysql DB management - hours for each student

Tags: mysql

I am going to write some code to retrieve and add to/remove from a student's hours that they have signed up for. For example...

- student 1:

  - October 20th:

    - 12am
    - 4pm
    - 7pm
  - October 21st:

    - 8pm
- student 2

  - October 19th

    - 1pm
    - 6pm

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to create this type of table setup on phpmyadmin with each student having a dynamic number of hours, and different times, and different days. I am new to mysql management, am vaguely familiar with joins and stuff, and am just now starting to expand my database to more complex things like this. What I have learned so far is that enums is NOT where I want to go. Just unsure of a starting point...

What is a good strategy for doing something like this?

Thank you,

Comment: Protip: Stop thinking in terms of the 12-hour clock system and embrace 24-hour UTC.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend you get used to writing `CREATE TABLE` statements by hand instead of using phpMyAdmin. Have you considered using a tool like MySQL Workbench instead?

Comment: I agree, bro. I'm going to do that. Either way you think about it, it's different hours. That's not the part that confuses me, though...Also, I don't know if you know, but phpmyadmin allows you to write Create Tables by hand. You can do it the GUI interface way OR normal mysql statements way.

Comment: So what does confuse you?

Comment: What confuses me is how to create a table that has each student, but then they have dynamic hours as well as a dynamic quantity of hours as well as a dynamic quantity of days. I don't think you can do it with just one table because a table as far as I know it has to be n x n. I don't know how to do this with multiple tables...

Comment: But in your post you wrote that you're "familiar with joins and stuff" - which implies you understand `1:m` multiplicity and foreign-key constraints.

Comment: ok, fair enough. I changed it to "vaguely" familiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you need to create many to many relation**

first i try to explain it simple and fast:
1- you need to make a table for hours, each hours have 1 row.
2- i guess you already have a student table
3- now you need a table that contain only 2  column, first column is hours table id, second column is student id.

at the end you simply need to execute select command like this:

```
select * from StudentHours Table where student-id = 1;
```

Detailed Information:

Relational database systems usually don't allow you to implement a direct many-to-many relationship between two tables. Consider the example of keeping track of invoices. If there were many invoices with the same invoice number and one of your customers inquired about that invoice number, you wouldn't know which number they were referring to. This is one reason for assigning a unique value to each invoice.

To avoid this problem, you can break the many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships by using a third table, called a join table. Each record in a join table includes a match field that contains the value of the primary keys of the two tables it joins. (In the join table, these match fields are foreign keys.) These foreign key fields are populated with data as records in the join table are created from either table it joins.

A typical example of a many-to many relationship is one between students and classes. A student can register for many classes, and a class can include many students.

The following example includes a Students table, which contains a record for each student, and a Classes table, which contains a record for each class. A join table, Enrollments, creates two one-to-many relationships—one between each of the two tables.

[image: Example of many to many Relationship]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I think I am starting to get it. Two questions. If I need the day that the students scheduled for would I have a '3-many relationship?' so I would just add a table for days, and tac that id onto the student_hours table, although it would be student_hrs_days table? Second question is on that select command. It looks like that selects certain student id's so I would want to do some join or inner-join statement to bring them all together for each student when I want to store it? Thanks again.

Comment: you are wellcome bro, but no , the many2many relationship can contain everything, for example you just need to add a day column to your hour table. exactly , you have to use inner join , i didnt pointed that because its already making everyone confused. but its not hard, start to build your database, after started that you see its simple, you can use the phpmyadmin visual designer, that can make it Very EZ

Comment: if you still have problem i can try to show you with teamviewer or anydesk,

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. I'll try it out tomorrow, and then I'll get into the join and inner-join stuff. At least I have direction for tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sure, just remember, it look like super hard, but its very ez, just start,

Comment: Including mathematical operators in table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically bad idea.

Comment: Also, while I recognise that 'associative' or 'junction' tables are colloquially named all kinds of things, if you're attempting to provide some kind of canonical answer, it's probably best to call them 'associative' or 'junction' tables.